# Execute a function when tour end in React Joyride

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have to execute a function when my tour ends. I'm using **REACT-JOYRIDE** package.
Let say I have 5 tour steps. When the 5th step is done I want to execute a function.
How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-voice-h3mnyp?file=/src/Basic/index.tsx
this examples can fix you issue